# C# Parallel Foreach using local and non-local variables

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I’m having some trouble understating how to make variables local using parallel threads. In a nutshell, I have a list of `SingleRecord`s called `RecordList`. With some logic based on the `SingleRecord` variable I have some local variables.  I was hoping to have each parallel thread have its own `IntVal` and `StringVal` and then add those to a table that all parallel threads can access. Been reading some on this but am not sure I fully understand quite how it works.

```
DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();
DataTable MyTable = MyDataSet.Tables.Add();

MyTable.Columns.Add("NumberVal", typeof(int));
MyTable.Columns.Add("TextVal", typeof(string));

Parallel.ForEach(RecordList, SingleRecord =>
{
    int IntVal = 0;
    string StringVal = string.Empty;

    IntVal = some logic;
    StringVal = SingleRecord + some logic; 

    MyTable.Rows.Add(IntVal, StringVal);
 });
```

Comment: What is this `IntVal` supposed to be?

Comment: We need to know what `some logic` is and does - because that could be doing something that violates thread-safety.

Comment: IntVal and StringVal are just local variables I'm saving based on the value of 'SingleRecord'. I'm more or less parsing that SingleRecord to pull various things out. I just simplified my variable list in my actual code within my 'ForEach' just to make it easier to read. I'm essentially getting a block of text I'm trying to parse and convert into a data table.

Comment: The problem is `MyTable.Rows.Add(IntVal, StringVal);` is not safe for use in asynchronous scenarios. Instead, you'll need to return rows to the main thread and add them all from that location. You can do the work to calculate what a rows needs to look like in parallel, but the final operation to add to the datatable needs to be one at a time.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That operation is synchronous, not asynchronous.  It is multithreaded though, and *that* is the problem.  The operation is not safe for use from multiple threads.

Comment: Alright - so the actual adding to the table is the issue, not the variables in the ForEach themselves. Should I not modify variables I declare externally to the ForEach within when using Parallel threads? How would I have a parallel thread 'return' a formatted row to add to my table?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to use a concurrent collection to keep each iteration processing result, and then convert the result to the data table. For example,

```
private static void RunString()
        {
            var recordList = new List<string> {"1", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"};

            var result = new ConcurrentBag<ProcessedData>();
            Parallel.ForEach(recordList
                , record => //body
                {
                    var integerValue = record.Length;
                    var processedString = record + " Processed";

                    var processedData = new ProcessedData
                    {
                        IntegerValue = integerValue,
                        StringValue = processedString
                    };
                    result.Add(processedData);
                });

            var myDataSet = new DataSet();
            var myTable = myDataSet.Tables.Add();

            myTable.Columns.Add("NumberVal", typeof(int));
            myTable.Columns.Add("TextVal", typeof(string));
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.IntegerValue} has {item.StringValue}");
                myTable.Rows.Add(item.IntegerValue, item.StringValue);
            }
        }

        private sealed class ProcessedData
        {
            internal int IntegerValue { get; set; }
            internal string StringValue { get; set; }
        }
```

This code prints the following values
[image]

Comment: Ah alright - so that puts all my thread variables into a thread safe ConcurrentBag and once all my threads are done then I loop through said bags and add them to my data table. I think that is bridging the gap of what I wasn't understanding. I assumed (incorrectly) that my thread variables were being messed up by other instances of the thread. I'll give this a try - Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure ConcurrentBag is needed here, he is only supposed to add elements and later after concurrency is done, process them in a single thread environment

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question but I think you're asking: in your code that's working as expected, why does it work?

```
SingleRecord =>
    {
        int IntVal = 0;
        string StringVal = string.Empty;

        IntVal = some logic;
        StringVal = SingleRecord + some logic; 

        MyTable.Rows.Add(IntVal, StringVal);
    }
```

In this section of code, you are saying "for each singlerecord, call this function with it". The key is, you're creating an anonymous function and passing that into ForEach.  It is not evaluated immediately.

The anonymous function declares its own local variables within its function block so those are only in scope for that iteration (in this case, for each record).